# When Using django forms in wagtail Page, how to handle request.method == 'POST'?

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms, wagtail

I cannot handle the request when the user submits the form.

I am rendering my form in the get_context() method in the HomePage class:

```
def get_context(self, request):
    context = super(HomePage, self).get_context(request)

    from .forms import RosaleaContactForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RosaleaContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = request.POST['subject']
            name = request.POST['from_name']
            message = request.POST['message']
            to_email = request.POST['from_email']
            from_phone = request.POST['from_phone']

            send_mail(
                subject,
                name,
                message,
                from_email,
                [to_email],
                fail_silently=False,
            )

            form = form
    else:
        form = RosaleaContactForm()

    context['form'] = form
    return context
```

The form renders in the page, I am using crispy forms and re_captcha but I cannot handle the request when the form is submitted.

1. Do I need a new view to handle the request?
2. Do I use the serve method?
3. Submit the form with AJAX?

If I want the form on a separate page I am using the serve method and it all works but serve overrides everything and I cannot use my home page template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should override the page's `serve` method. This is the closest equivalent in Wagtail to Django's view functions, as it lets you return any HTTP response you like depending on the outcome of your form handling - either rendering a template (most easily using Django's `django.shortcuts.render` helper) or something else such as redirecting away.

See [wagtail-form-example](https://github.com/gasman/wagtail-form-example/commits/master) for a worked example of implementing a Django form as a Wagtail page.

Answer (score 8):

From gasman's answer:
It works.

```
def serve(self, request):
        from flavours.forms import FlavourSuggestionForm

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = FlavourSuggestionForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                flavour = form.save()
                return render(request, 'flavours/thankyou.html', {
                    'page': self,
                    'flavour': flavour,
                })
        else:
            form = FlavourSuggestionForm()

        return render(request, 'flavours/suggest.html', {
            'page': self,
            'form': form,
        })
```